# Is there a way to reduce the slot required for innate spell?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, feats, magic

Innate spell is awesome, but rather expensive for higher level spells.

Is there a way to reduce the 8 slots up requirement for taking it?

---

I am aware there is a version from the player's guide to faerun that uses a slot of the same level as the spell, but only allows 3x/day uses. This is not the version of the feat i'm talking about.

Comment: would "easy metamagic" work?
Likely not, since Innate spell is not metamagic.
But I'm guessing that's the direction you're looking in.

Answer (score 2):

No, nothing in the game modifies the Innate Spell feat in any way.

There are a few high-optimization tricks to *reduce* the effective level of a spell, instead. These are rather dubious applications of strictly-favorable-RAW, generally revolving around +0 metamagic feats (e.g. Invisible Spell) and then applying metamagic cost reducers. Most of these indicate that they cannot reduce things below +0, but a few neglect to include that limitation and thus could be used to, *arguably*, allow the metamagic’d spell to be selected for Innate Spell.

On the other hand, it’s not clear that you could select a metamagic’d spell for Innate Spell in the first place, so even if you buy that kind of reduction works, it’s *still* dubious for Innate Spell.

And on the other end of the spectrum, you could artificially increase the effective highest level of spell you can cast. A dragonwrought kobold can take [Improved Spell Capacity](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/feats.htm#improvedSpellCapacity) due to their Dragon type as soon as they manage the highest-level spells in a given class, which they can also accelerate through the usual shenanigans (Sanctum Spell, Earth Spell, Versatile Spellcaster, etc. etc.). Getting 8 levels’ worth of increased spell capacity is dicey and would require a lot of feats, but it is do-able (and much less dubious, RAW, than lowering a spell’s level, though of course practically speaking it’s probably even worse for the game).

Beyond that, the archmage’s spell-like ability high arcana has similar functionality, and can be used on higher-level spells, but it only twice per day, not at will. Likewise, the version of Innate Spell in *Player’s Guide to Faerûn* lacks any spell-level limitation, but only allows you to use the resulting spell-like ability thrice per day.

Ultimately, to *really* get a lot of at-will spell-like abilities, you need to play a warlock or other invoker. The obvious trade-offs with this are obvious.

And really, ultimately, there are few spells that really care about at-will usage. Innate Spell really isn’t that great a feat, for the same reasons that warlock isn’t that great a class.

Comment: The archmage ability really only saves you from burning a feat, at the cost of a 5th level slot. Because the PGtF version is a +0 metamagic feat that does it 3x/day already, and with one less required feat than the +8 one. Thanks.

Comment: @Mindwin I thought we were *not* talking about the PGtF version? That’s what the question states. Anyway, the archmage high arcana lacks any level limit, so it is a way to get a higher-level spell made “innate” (kinda not really, as indicated in the answer).

Comment: Yeah, but since the first line of the answer debunks the whole question, lets dig into the alternatives and compare them for discussion's sake. It is fun. Maybe even edit the Q some to better fit the A. I left that last line there to avoid the "most obvious" kind of answer that would say "use the PGtF version doh"

Comment: @Mindwin Well, OK, I’ve added the mention of the PGtF version of the feat to the answer, alongside the high arcana.

Answer (score 0):

Something of a technicality, but it requires that you be able to cast the spell, and that you spend a spell slot of however many levels higher.  It never specifies what kind of spell it must be, or that the spell slot so expended must be the same kind of spell.  This, if you have access to, say, a copy of Trapsmith haste (lvl 1) that you can cast, you might arguably be able to cash in a lvl 9 sorcerer or wizard spell to get it as an innate, in spite of it being lvl 3 on the wizard/sorceror list.

...and, of course, this leads into all sorts of shenanigans around the definition of "a spell you can cast"... especially since the ability to cast the spell isn't a requirement of the feat - it just constrains the decisions you can make at the time you take the feat.  If you lose the ability to cast it due to losing cleric powers, you lose the innate spell, but other ways of losing it (Running out of scrolls?  How cheesy does your DM permit you to be?) don't appear to.